# Knockout JS - For evaluation of computer properties from another method

Tags: knockout.js

Ok so this is a bit of an odd situation however I don't think it's that uncommon but alas my Google-fu is weak on this one.

so here is the scenario, I have one VM (koQuestion) that accepts a function that determines if the question should be shown or not. I am passing in a function that checks the value of another koQuestion (q2) to see if the question (q2a) should be displayed.

My problem is that q2a is always displayed and it does not reevaluate the computed isDisplayed function on q2a when the value of q2 is changed. I found this thread (https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1019) and tried the forcibleComputed method but it still isn't functioning.

I couldn't get the code to paste in here for some strange reason so i created a 
fiddle to illustrate the problem.

this is the problem instance of the VM

```
var KoQuestion = function koQ(text, manditory, displayCondition, type, formId) {
    var self = this;

    var regEx = /^\d{1,5}[az]?\.?\t?/;

    self.Text = text;
    self.Required = manditory;
    self.isDisplayed = ko.computed(function qDisplay() {
        if (!displayCondition)
            return true;

        return displayCondition();
    }, self);

    self.Type = type;
    self.FormId = formId;
    self.Name = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.Text.replace(regEx, '');
    });
    self.Value = ko.observable('');
    self.rdoValue = ko.computed(function () {
        var selectedVal = "";
        var selected = $("input[type='radio'][name='" + self.FormId + "']:checked");
        if (selected.length > 0) {
            selectedVal = selected.val();
        }
        self.Value = selectedVal;
        return selectedVal;
    });
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/SneeKeeFahk/3nkachhw/1/

Comment: what exactly is the problem you are having? also, you've mashed together two types of function definitions into one. it's either `var name = function(params)` or `function name(params)`

Comment: hey @dperry, adding a name to anonymous functions is perfectly fine and it also helps when debugging because you wont just see (anonymous function) in the stack trace.

I updated my question to have a link to a jsFiddle illustrating my problem. For some reason i couldn't post the code without getting errors.

Comment: There is a reason why you are forced to include a code block. So include the relevant parts of the code *in your question*.

Comment: Hey @MattBurland, I tried adding the code block but i just kept getting an unspecified error with no details as to why. I will try to add it back in again.

Comment: @MattBurland I posted to http://meta.stackexchange.com/ with a description of my problem trying add the code block. Here's hoping i cant get an answer because im being downvoted due to the lack of code blocks.

Comment: I edited your question to paste in the first code VM which I *assume* is the part you wanted. Works fine for me (the copy / paste that is)

Comment: You seem to be doing your binding backwards here. Your VM shouldn't have to access the view to get data (which you do in `self.rdoValue` when you use a jquery selector). Your view should bind your view model, not the other way around.

Comment: @MattBurland Wow, that is annoying but thank you for taking the time to add that for me. I think you might be onto something and it's a fundamental misunderstanding of the bindings on my part. Thanks for all the help and patience, I will remove the rdoValue property all together, that was just me trying to get this working, and go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem was with the binding in your View:

```
<!-- if: isDisplayed() -->
```

That should be:

```
<!-- ko if: isDisplayed() -->
```

Otherwise Knockout doesn't know that it's supposed to worry about it at all.

Then I would change your binding of the radio buttons because it's backwards. Your view model *should not* have to access your view by selecting parts of the DOM. Your view is supposed to bind your view model, not the other way arround. Try something like this:

```
self.rdoValue = ko.observable('');
```

And then bind like this:

```
<input type="radio" value="Yes" data-bind="attr: { 'name': FormId }, css: { mandatory: Required }, checked: rdoValue" class="awlc" />
```

The important part being using the [checked](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) binding not the `value` binding.

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3nkachhw/5/)

Comment: Thanks again for all the help Matt. You truly are both a gentleman and a scholar. I would upvote this but I can't so you just need to live with it being an accepted answer.